# How do I use "USE" key word to designate a database whose name has periods?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We can use

```
USE master
```

to designate a database.

However, my database name has periods, like `mydb.1.2.3`. Executing

```
USE mydb.1.2.3
```

results in an error:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Database 'mydb' does not exist
> Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

I also tried

```
USE "mydb.1.2.3"
```

and

```
USE {mydb.1.2.3}
```

both didn't work.

Comment: Did you try square brackets, as in  `[mydb.1.2.3]`?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, using object names that do not conform to the rules for naming identifiers is, while possible, not recommended.

specifying a database name to include a period `.` is further to be avoided since `.` designates object hierarchies, ie *DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName*.

If an object name includes non-standard characters it must be *delimted* using either "quotes" or preferably [square brackets].

If quotes did not work it indicates your `quoted_identifier` option is set `off` - this is also not recommended, it should always be `on`

The documentation [explains the rules for identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15) and for [quoted_identifer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) options.